# best practices for navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

When an user opens the app, he/she will see the detail controller. There is a problem since there are two view controllers, list and detail. I would like to start with the detail controller then go back to the list (left swipe).

Right now, I have a view controller per a storyboard. I like that and it is clean. I would like to keep it. And, there will be more detail controllers (types of detail). It'll have a list of the detail controllers to pick one in the list controller.

I tried having the list with navigation controller in a storyboard but the detail controller doesn't have navigation controller so the pop from the nav stack didn't work.

I googled and there are some solutions -

1. Create a singleton for navigation controller in AppDelegate and add the view controllers in the stack. But not sure how I can add the list controller then detail controller.
2. Segues?
3. Any other ideas?
4. Coordinator pattern (overkill for this simple app)?

Comment: Do you want to add both list and details view controllers into a navigation controller and then displaying the second (details) view controller directly with displaying back (pop) on the navigation bar?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted, how will we approach this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, you should deal with it programmatically when the app gets launched. What you could do to achieve it is to create a navigation controller, containing the list and the details view controllers and set it as the window root view controller. Example (assuming that both view controllers are in the Main storyboard):

```
var window: UIWindow!


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    let firstVC = ListViewController.storyboardInstance()
    let secondVC = DefaultNoteController.storyboardInstance()

    let navigation = UINavigationController()
    navigation.viewControllers = [firstVC, secondVC] as! [UIViewController]
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window.rootViewController = navigation


    return true
}
```

According to this, the app should display the second view controller in the navigation controller (details) with a navigation bar containing a back button.

Comment: what value should Main storyboard file base name have? The key/value is in Info.plist. I use it to launch the storyboard.

Comment: @Meep if you are using storyboard in your project, the default one should be "Main"...

Comment: perfect - I got it working, and edited your answer to clarify an issue with window. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help @Meep. I don't really think that you should do `window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)`, it should be done automatically for you...

Comment: that's odd, I'm getting window as a unknown identifier.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a navigation controller but you want the user to be able to swipe left to go "back" from the initial detail v.c. to the master v.c., it seems to me that what you want is a UIPageViewController, which provides exactly this swipe capability.

However, if this really is a master-detail situation, then I think you *should* use a navigation controller if you are not using one now, because that the natural expression of master-detail; it is what the user will expect, and will make things much simpler for you as the app evolves. There is no difficulty about launching the app initially into the detail view controller, within the navigation controller. So that's the approach I actually recommend.

Comment: yes,  I kept forth and back to not use/use navigation controller. I decided to use navigation controller since it's really much easier. Thank you!